# Video - stream slow using s3 content store

Tags: spring-boot, spring-content-community-project

Video - stream - this works.. however on larger files it is slow..
How can I improve the content s3 store to deliver the content faster ?

I have tried returning a byte array and copy to a buffer.. all load.. just slow... I am not sure where the bottle neck is coming from..

```
  Optional<File> f = filesRepo.findById(id);
        if (f.isPresent()) {
            InputStreamResource inputStreamResource = new InputStreamResource(contentStore.getContent(f.get()));
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentLength(f.get().getContentLength());
            headers.set("Content-Type", f.get().getMimeType());
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(inputStreamResource, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

also get this warning:
Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error and may result in sub-optimal behavior. Request only the bytes you need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use.

Comment: https://www.findjar.com/jar/com/github/paulcwarren/spring-content-s3/0.0.5/spring-content-s3-0.0.5.jar.html

found this... trying it now... hope this helps someone..

Comment: If that helps you, try answering your question. Wait for couple of days to see if someone comes up with a better answer, and then accept the appropriate answer. Its not an issue eve if you end up accepting your own answer.

Comment: Well that helped to import the correct libs.. but now can't get it to find the bucket.. updated the question..

Comment: now having this new issue.. slow loading of the video..

Comment: Given you are return a ResponseEntity you trying to stream video over a REST endpoint I assume?  Are you aware that there is a separate module spring-content-rest that adds content-related endpoints for you so you don't have to do this yourself.   These endpoints also support byte-ranges that support standard video playback controls which the above code won't do.

Comment: Thank you @PaulWarren